# Bootstrap dropdown not working with SlidesJS 3.0

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slidesjs

I have the site hosted on Dropbox at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/833721/gapsummit/london/index.html

The 'events' dropdown works on all pages except /london/index.html
The only difference on this page is that SlidesJS is used.

If I comment out the CSS import, it works perfectly.

```
<!--SLIDER CSS CLASES -->
  <link href="../assets/Slides-SlidesJS-3/examples/playing/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ the slider style file there is role

```
.navbar {
overflow: hidden
}
```

which is the same class of the top header try to force the top header to have overflow of visible by adding the following

```
.navbar-fixed-top
{
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you be a bit more specific? I'm not very good with CSS, hence using Bootstrap. :)

Comment: I managed to find this within bootstrap.css: .navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}    ....... there is no overflow: hidden clause.

Comment: don't change in the bootstrap file directly, ".navbar-fixed-top
{
overflow: hidden !important;
}"  add that to style.css

Comment: Hi Hager, Thanks for that. I added it to style.css, but now the dropdown doesn't work anywhere? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/833721/gapsummit/london/index.html

Comment: sorry sorry
.navbar-fixed-top { overflow: visible !important; }